# Spinner Working improperly

Tags: android, json, arraylist, spinner

I've tried many tutorials with no use to solve this error am facing .
The error is that the spinner is filled with data but once i select any then it gets blank selected item
here are the two pics : 
[image]

[image]

and here is the code snippet :

```js
package com.school;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AdminAddAbsence extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
 
 Spinner spinnerStudentId;
 Button bAddStudentAbsence,bBack;
 EditText etAdminAddAbsenceDate;
 DatePicker dpAdminAddAbsenceDate;
 JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> students;
 ArrayList<String>items;
 ArrayList<Student>studentsList;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.admin_add_absence);
  initVars();
 }

 private void initVars() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  bAddStudentAbsence = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdminAddAbsenceAdd);
  bAddStudentAbsence.setOnClickListener(this);
  bBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdminAddAbsenceBack);
  bBack.setOnClickListener(this);
  spinnerStudentId = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAdminAddAbsenceStudentId);
  etAdminAddAbsenceDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAdminAddAbsenceDate);
  dpAdminAddAbsenceDate = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpAdminAddAbsenceDate);
  
  students = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
  new getStudents().execute();
  
   SimpleAdapter sAdap;
   sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(AdminAddAbsence.this, students, R.layout.spinner_details,
   new String[] {"studentID", "studentName"}, new int[] {R.id.tvSpinnerDetailsStudentId, R.id.tvSpinnerDetailsStudentName});
   spinnerStudentId.setAdapter(sAdap);
   
   spinnerStudentId.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
     int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String studentID = students.get(position).get("studentID")
       .toString();
       String sName = students.get(position).get("studentName")
       .toString();
       Toast.makeText(AdminAddAbsence.this, studentID + " "+sName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(AdminAddAbsence.this, "Nothing selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  });
  
 }

 public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch(v.getId()){
  case R.id.bAdminAddAbsenceBack:
   finish();
   break;
  }
 }
 class getStudents extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     try {
     List<NameValuePair>param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("OPERATION", "GET_STUDENTS"));
     JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(Utils.OPERATIONS_URL, "POST", param);
     
      JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("database");
      HashMap<String, String>map;
      for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
       map = new HashMap<String, String>();
       JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
       int studentID = jsonObject.getInt("idStudent");
       String studentName = jsonObject.getString("name");
       map.put("studentID", studentID+"");
       map.put("studentName", studentName);
       students.add(map);
      }
     } catch (JSONException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     
    
   
   return null;
  }
  
 }
  class Student {

  // Okay, full acknowledgment that public members are not a good idea, however
  // this is a Spinner demo not an exercise in java best practices.
  public int id = 0;
  public String name = "";

  // A simple constructor for populating our member variables for this tutorial.
  public Student( int _id, String _name)
  {
      id = _id;
      name = _name;
  }
  

  public int getId() {
   return id;
  }


  public void setId(int id) {
   this.id = id;
  }


  public String getName() {
   return name;
  }


  public void setName(String name) {
   this.name = name;
  }


  // The toString method is extremely important to making this class work with a Spinner
  // (or ListView) object because this is the method called when it is trying to represent
  // this object within the control.  If you do not have a toString() method, you WILL
  // get an exception.
  public String toString()
  {
      return( "("+name +")");
  }
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: when you don't select, whether the Spinner is blank or not?

Comment: before modifying the code yes it was blank ,but after i modified my code in my answer below , its default selection is the first selection of the returned array

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this within onItemSelected method

```
spinnerStudentId.setSelection(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : 
the solution that solved this problem is that i put the adapter itself in the doInBackground method of the AsyncTask class but inside the inner runOnUIThread because you will not be able to modify on the UI in the AsyncTask class except in this anonymous class .
so here is the modified AsyncTask Class

```js
class getStudents extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   try {
    List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("OPERATION", "GET_STUDENTS"));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
      Utils.OPERATIONS_URL, "POST", param);

    JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("database");
    HashMap<String, String> map;
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     map = new HashMap<String, String>();
     JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
     int studentID = jsonObject.getInt("idStudent");
     String studentName = jsonObject.getString("name");
     map.put("studentID", studentID + "");
     map.put("studentName", studentName);
     students.add(map);
     
    }
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     
     public void run() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      SimpleAdapter sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(AdminAddAbsence.this, students,
        R.layout.spinner_details, new String[] { "studentID",
          "studentName" }, new int[] {
          R.id.tvSpinnerDetailsStudentId,
          R.id.tvSpinnerDetailsStudentName });
      spinnerStudentId.setAdapter(sAdap);
      spinnerStudentId
        .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
           int position, long id) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          String studentID = students.get(position)
            .get("studentID").toString();
          String sName = students.get(position)
            .get("studentName").toString();
          etAdminAddAbsenceDate.setText(studentID);
          Toast.makeText(AdminAddAbsence.this,
            parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
         }

         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Toast.makeText(AdminAddAbsence.this,
            "Nothing selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
        });
     }
    });
    
   } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return null;
  }

 }
```